Django 'IntegerField' object has no attribute 'get_internal_type'
So guys i have been trying to use the ExpressionWrapper in django and get outputfield as a IntegerField(), I don't know where I am going wrong
The imports
# Imports from django.core
from attr import fields
from django.db import models
from django.db.models import DecimalField, IntegerField, Avg,Subquery,OuterRef, Q, Sum, F, ExpressionWrapper
from django.db.models.functions import ExtractYear
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.forms import DateField, DecimalField, IntegerField
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404
from django.utils import timezone

# Imports froms apps
from shop.models import CartItem, Order, OrderItem, Product, Review
from wallets.models import Transaction, Wallet

This is code part of a model method
 Profile.objects.filter(
            id__in = Wallet.objects.filter(
            id__in=purchases_made_for_on_store_products.values('wallet')
            ).values('user')
            ).values('dob').annotate(
                age = ExpressionWrapper(ExtractYear(dt.today()) -  ExtractYear(F('dob')),
                output_field=IntegerField()))
            )

I was expecting the code to calculate the age of each of each user and store it temporarily in in a field called "age". this would allow me to annotate it and further used for filtering.

The year will (likely) not be calculated however, or at least not correctly.

id__in = Wallet.objects.filter(...) also looks suspicious, since you here match Profile ids with Wallet ids? Can you share the related models? That will probably make it a lot easier.

You're importing IntegerField twice, overriding the model field import:
from django.db.models import DecimalField, IntegerField,...
...
from django.forms import ..., IntegerField

Make sure you use the model field in your queryset, for example by giving the form field a different name:
from django.forms import IntegerField as IntegerFormField


You probably don't even need the expression wrapper, you can extract the year and the year of the day of birth:
Profile.objects.filter(
    id__in=Wallet.objects.filter(
        id__in=purchases_made_for_on_store_products.values('wallet')
    ).values('user')
).values('dob').annotate(age=dt.today().year - ExtractYear('dob'))
But now the bad news, this is not the age: you are determining the year minus the year of birth. So if someone is born in 1993 for example, you assume that that person will always be 31 years old, even if he is born on October 14th for example, and thus it takes some extra days. You will need to compare the day of birth as well thus.

So, I will have to use the date of birth as instead of extracting the year, is that correct

Actually it happened  'IntegerField' object has no attribute 'get_internal_type', usually occurs when there's a confusion between model fields and form fields. In your code, you imported both the model IntegerField and the form IntegerField. You should use the model IntegerField for ExpressionWrapper.
from django.db import models
from django.db.models import DecimalField, IntegerField, Avg, Subquery, OuterRef, Q, Sum, F, ExpressionWrapper
from django.db.models.functions import ExtractYear
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404
from django.utils import timezone

# Imports from apps
from shop.models import CartItem, Order, OrderItem, Product, Review
from wallets.models import Transaction, Wallet

# Import datetime to get the current year
from datetime import datetime

# Profile model method example
Profile.objects.filter(
    id__in=Wallet.objects.filter(
        id__in=purchases_made_for_on_store_products.values('wallet')
    ).values('user')
).values('dob').annotate(
    age=ExpressionWrapper(
        datetime.now().year - ExtractYear(F('dob')),
        output_field=IntegerField()
    )
)

